# Speed up table scans using a middle-man data dump table

Tags: sql-server

I'm a dev (not dba) working on a project where we have been managing "updates" to data via bulk insert. However we first insert to a non-indexed "pre-staging" table. This is due to the fact that we need to normalize a lot of denormalized data and make sure it's properly split up into our schema.

Naturally this makes the update and insert processes slow since we have to check if the information exists for each specific table with non-indexed codes or identifiers.

Since the "pre-staging" table is truncated we didn't include auto-generated IDs either.

I'm looking into ways to speed up table scans on that particular table in our stored procedures. What would be the best approach to do so? Indexes? Auto-generated IDs as clustered indexes? This last one is tricky because we cannot establish relationships with our "staging" data since it is truncated per data dump.

Comment: Very broad question, I would recommend creating indexes on this table after load or using clustered columnstore index.

Comment: Is it on the "staging" table that table scans are performing too slowly? How many rows does it contain? If your processing logic involves a lot of lookups against the staging table, then clearly applying one or more indexes to the staging table should increase the speed of these.

Comment: I looked up columnstore indexes and it seems like a potential solution. What do you mean "after load" though? I suppose you mean after a bulk insert?

Comment: no @Steve the scans are mostly on the pre-staging table as i established.

Comment: @Nimchip, I meant the "pre-staging table". If appropriate indexes don't solve the problem, then it may be the query or procedure itself is inefficiently drafted..

Comment: yes inefficient procedures are our #1 concern but running Plan Explorer we are noticing Table Scans on the pre-staging table are taking a huge hit. Again we have the situation where this table is truncated on every bulk insert for example. I am looking into columnstore index like @Piotr commented, however.